# How to make an element positioned into right:0, if it already has left:0 style in one of it's class

Tags: css

I have an element with class A, with rules:

```
.A {
    left: 0px;
}
```

For some reason, I need to make the element at the right position inside the container and I cannot exclude A class.

Comment: override them with inheritance  .container .A {left : auto; right : 0;}

Answer (score 2):

**Specificity is your friend here:**

Here's a couple of options....

Override the class using additional specificity such as **another class** (or ID)

```css
.container {
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  bordeR: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
}
.A {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.A.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A right"></div>
</div>
```

or a **nth-child selector**

```css
.container {
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  bordeR: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
}
.A {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.A:nth-child(2) {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="A"></div>
</div>
```